# How to write nice queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, algorithm

I came from non-computer-science background and Now I am working as a Ruby on rails developer who using active_record to fetch values from database.While I reading rails scalability issues, many places I found `'N query' 'N + 1 queries' 'N log N'` which I am not familiar with.I want you people to help me by explaining what all these and where I could get a nice blog or website which explaining all these terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 separate things here:

1. N log N, N^2 etc. These refer to the running time of an algorithm as a function of the size of its input
2. The term N + 1 queries refers to a very specific issue. Assume that you have your standard blogging example app, with Post and Author as models. I might choose to collect all the names of the authors who have actually written something:

   names = Post.all.collect { |post| post.author.name}

This triggers one extra SQL query for each post, so if you had N posts then you'd end up doing N+1 queries. All those extra ones would be very fast query but the overhead/latency adds up quickly so it can slow stuff right down

The [Rails active record guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) explains this and the mitigations rails makes available.

Answer (score 2):

Those three examples are shorthand ways of describing how much work the algorithm is required to do to get the final result.

Look here for more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions